# How to show DropdownList Validation message, If we select default text

Tags: sitecore-forms

I have to show required error message, if i'm selecting default text in dropdownlist, Is there any option to show this validation message.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can set the following option for this control in the form builder:

Validation -> Field importance:  Mandatory.

Next, for the "Select..." option you can set the value as " " - so it would be saved by the form editor.

So now if the "Select..." option is selected, on the form submission this control will be marked with a "required" error message.

Another possible option would be to create a custom drop-down (copy on existing one) control with custom validation and custom parameter for empty option value - like "0" as on your screens shot.

Answer (score 1):

Modify DropdownList.cshtml found under C:\inetpub\wwwroot\yoursite.dev.com\Views\FormBuilder\FieldTemplates

Update the following

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Items)
{
    <option value="@item.Value" selected="@item.Selected">@item.Text</option>
}
```

with the follwing

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Items)
{
    <option value="@item.Value.Trim()" selected="@item.Selected">@item.Text</option>
}
```

Instead of "0", I have just validated on empty value(value should be space). Since there could be possibilty of using "0" elsewhere.